# Pandas: How to preserve _id when parsing nested list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access a nested list within a pandas DataFrame, but when I do so I somehow cannot hold on to the `_id`. But the `_id` is needed for later processing.

The DataFrame looks like, where coordinates is a list of floats:

```
    _id                         coordinates
0   6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ee    [47.95816055, 12.470216551879616]
1   6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ef    [51.46471555, 13.026622019540596]
2   6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f0    [51.141569849999996, 10.40367219787925]
3   6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f1    [53.5104874, 12.847652330627001]
4   6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f2    [52.196924, 11.396162132482953]
...
```

Same DataFrame as dictionary:

```
{'_id': {0: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ee'),   1: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ef'),   2: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f0'),   3: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f1'),   4: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f2')},  'coordinates': {0: [47.95816055, 12.470216551879616],   1: [51.46471555, 13.026622019540596],   2: [51.141569849999996, 10.40367219787925],   3: [53.5104874, 12.847652330627001],   4: [52.196924, 11.396162132482953]}}
```

The DataFrame is being parsed to grab lat and lng values

```
c_dict = []
for c in data['coordinates']:  
  c_dict.append({'lat': c[0], 'lng': c[1]})
coords_df = pd.DataFrame(c_dict)
```

The output is now missing the document `_id`
[image: Output after parsing the DataFrame]

The data is now being filtered, i.e. "Which lat > 52.00?"

```
north = coords_df[coords_df.lat > 52.00]
north

Output:
    lat        lng
3   53.510487  12.847652
4   52.196924  11.396162
```

By using `north.index` I am able to retrieve the DataFrame indices and could use these again to filter the starting DataFrame.
I believe, that this is not the most efficient way to do so, but can also not figure out how to optimize the process.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a copy-paste ready excerpt of your data?  df.head().to_dict() would be superb.

Comment: @Correy-Koshnick 

`{'_id': {0: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ee'),   1: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ef'),   2: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f0'),   3: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f1'),   4: ObjectId('6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f2')},  'coordinates': {0: [47.95816055, 12.470216551879616],   1: [51.46471555, 13.026622019540596],   2: [51.141569849999996, 10.40367219787925],   3: [53.5104874, 12.847652330627001],   4: [52.196924, 11.396162132482953]}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .str.split(',').str[index] to extract lat/long and assign accordingly

**Data**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':['6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ee','6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ef','6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f0','6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f1','6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f2'],'coordinates':[[47.95816055, 12.470216551879616],[51.46471555, 13.026622019540596],[51.141569849999996, 10.40367219787925],[53.5104874, 12.847652330627001],[52.196924, 11.396162132482953]]})
```

**Solution**

```
df=df.assign(lat=df.coordinates.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str[0],long=df.coordinates.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str[1]).drop('coordinates',1)



                   _id                 lat                long
0  6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ee         47.95816055  12.470216551879616
1  6012fc07360d927bdb07b5ef         51.46471555  13.026622019540596
2  6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f0  51.141569849999996   10.40367219787925
3  6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f1          53.5104874  12.847652330627001
4  6012fc07360d927bdb07b5f2           52.196924  11.396162132482953
```

Proceed and filter as required;

```
df[df['lat'].gt('52.00')]
```

Comment: `data['coordinates']` is not a str but a list of floats, does this really work on a list?

Comment: Will look into that for you. The challenge was the way data was presented. a minute

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the description.

Comment: lets try `df=df.assign(lat=df.coordinates.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str[0],long=df.coordinates.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str[1]).drop('coordinates',1)`

Comment: It is working almost perfectly. Thank you.
Is there a way to cast the str to float right away or is this needed to happen in a separate step?

Comment: You mean make the lat/long float at computation? If so, please try `df=df.assign(lat=(df.coordinates.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str[0]).astype(float),long=df.coordinates.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(',').str[1].astype(float)).drop('coordinates',1)`

Comment: Now it's working like a charm. Thank you. Never would have thought of using str.split()

Answer (score 2):

you can save the id too in the dictionary using this code:

```
c_dict.append({'id':data['_id'],'lat': c[0], 'lng': c[1]})
```

Comment: OMG, why did I not see that? Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your problem please be sure to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Only looked good at first sight, but this stores the complete list of `_id`s within the dictionary. So each dictionary has now a list of all ids.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand the problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using apply to pull them from the list:

```
data['lat'] = data['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
data['lng'] = data['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```